# How to return a value from aspx page java script tag using "fireEvent" method?

Tags: javascript, c#, dom-events, javascript-framework

I am having multiple dropdownlists in my aspx page. Reletively I am populating all the dropdownlists one by one. The last dropdown list selected value should be returned to the calling environment when I click on the button. For that I added a script tag in aspx page and written a function which is working as onClick event. Please explain me how to create the event with that value and fire using fireEvent method. If it is not possible through fireEvent method please suggest any other way.

Comment: What do you mean by "Please explain me how to create the event with that value and fire using fireEvent method." ?

Comment: @Indikaf Thank you for your response.I mean the selected value of the last dropdown list should be binded to an event object and it should be fired such that I can handle that event objkect inside another javascript file where actually I am opening this aspx page as popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "returned to the calling environment"? If you want to show the selected value ,just use

```
var e = document.getElementById("ddl");
var valueddl= e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

To bind the value

```
function fireEvent(element,event){
    if (document.createEventObject){
    // dispatch for IE
    var evt = document.createEventObject();
    return element.fireEvent('on'+event,evt)
    }
    else{
    // dispatch for firefox + others
    var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    evt.initEvent(event, true, true ); // event type,bubbling,cancelable
    return !element.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
}

[html]
<input type="text" id="test">
<input type="text" id="testafterfired">
<script>
obj = document.getElementById("test");
Event.observe(obj,'change',function(){var e = document.getElementById("ddl");
var valueddl= e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;document.getElementById("testafterfired").value=valueddl;});
obj.fire('change');

</script>
[/html]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried to use your code. But it is giving the error like: " 'Event' is undefined ". Please look into the issue and help. Thanks in advance. Early response is appreciated.

Comment: ive changed fireEvent(obj,'change'); to obj.fire('change'); in my answer. What browser you are using?

Comment: I am using Internet Explorer. The Error is with the line:Event.observe...
In that line it is giving error as "Event" undefined.

Comment: I am unable to use Event object inside my aspx page script tag, help me to solve this issue. My aspx page contains asp header content and body content.

Comment: Look at this post- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351597/event-observe-change-events-not-being-triggered-in-ie